# how to get black border on only the color highlighted points in this facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- iris 


ggplot(d, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = d_bg, colour = "grey") +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  guides(colour = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

makes this:

[image]

but what I want is a black ring around each of the red, green, blue points

I tried this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = d_bg, colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(pch=21, color='black') + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  guides(colour = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

which seems close but overrides the coloring:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, this is an answer:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- iris 


ggplot(d, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(data = d_bg, colour = "grey") +
  geom_point(data=d, aes(fill=Species), color='black', pch=21) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```